# Avoid calling Activity Function by saving the response from the previous call

Tags: azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I have a durable function (Service Bus Trigger Azure Function) which contains an activity function that returns true/false. This function gets triggered every time a message is received from the queue. Currently a total of ~1000 messages are sent to the queue. And each time, this activity function is called and it returns true/false. Is there a way to save the return value from this activity function when the first message is received and when the remaining 999 messages are received, check the stored value instead of calling the activity function?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Durable Entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-entities?tabs=csharp) for this. This is part of Durable Functions so you don't need additional dependencies.

As soon as you have retrieved the value from the activity you can signal the entity to update the value using:

```
await client.SignalEntityAsync(entityId, activityResult);
```

And before you call the activity you can use:

```cs
var entityState = await client.ReadEntityStateAsync<T>(entityId);
if (!entityState.Exists) {
  // Call Activity
}
```

The question now is when to update the state of the entity. Because once the entity exists (the initial boolean value is set) the activity won't be called any longer. So you probably need to delete the entity at some point. In this case Durable Entities are used as a sort of cache and you have to determine when to invalidate the cache.